# java8 - absent variable & Optional

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-8

I am parsing input JSON. For a field, there are 3 possibilities:

- the field is absent;
- the value is set to null;
- the value is set to something valid.

Different behavior is implemented: for an absent value in the JSON, the default value is inserted into the database; for a null value in the JSON, a null value is inserted into the database.

I thought about `Optional` to model this:

```
public class Data {
    private Optional<String> field;
}
```

Which of the following two options make most sense?

1. If `field` is null, the field was absent in the JSON. If `field` is Optional.empty, the field is `null` in the JSON.
2. If `field` is null, the field was `null` in the JSON. If `field` is Optional.empty, the field is absent in the JSON.

FWIW, I am using Jackson with module jackson-datatype-jdk8 to parse the input JSON.

Comment: What is the meaning of the field being omitted? What is the meaning of the field being null? Is it the same?

Comment: Should the behavior be different in case of missing fields than in case of null?

Comment: Different behavior is implemented. For an absent value, the default value is inserted into the database. For a null value, a null value is inserted into the database.

Comment: With the same reasoning you could have `Optional<Optional<String>>`. It seems semantically easier to have a tri-state `Property<String>("default")` or such special class.

Comment: @JoopEggen Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9010622/125344 might be relevant. I think maintaining an "isSet" state for each property would be a useful alternative. Doing it with a tri-state class like what @JoopEggen suggests seems ideal.

Comment: @DaveTeezo I think my comment might not have sufficient quality. Ideally one would signal errors on required missing fields, not pass default values, and so on, maybe having one single static final _default_ object. Much depends on the usage, before overdesigning a class `Property<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you shouldn't use `Optional` for this scenario. As @dkatzel has mentioned in his answer, it's meant to be used as an API return value more than as a field.

Despite this academic discussion, you can accomplish what you want simply by initializing fields in your `Data` class to their default values:

```
public class Data {
    private String field = DEFAULT_VALUE;
}
```

And then let Jackson do the rest.

---

**EDIT as per OP's comment:**

When your JSON comes with a `null` value for the `field`, Jackson will set it to `null`, and that's what will be stored in the database.

When your JSON does not contain the field, the `DEFAULT_VALUE` will be automatically loaded in your `Data` instance.

And when your JSON does actually contain a value for the `field`, Jackson will set it, and that value will reach the database.

---

**EDIT 2, considering OP's requirement to find out if the `field` was either filled in, set to `null` or was absent in the input JSON, after parsing the JSON input:**

If, *after parsing the input JSON*, you need to know whether the `field` was either filled in, set to `null` or was absent, then consider this example, which shows the approach I'd take:

```
public class Data {

    private String field1 = "hello";

    private Integer field2 = 10;

    private Double field3 = 3.75;

    private static final Data DEFAULTS = new Data(); // defaults will be kept here

    public String getField1() {
        return this.field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public Integer getField2() {
        return this.field2;
    }

    public void setField2(Integer field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }

    public Double getField3() {
        return this.field3;
    }

    public void setField3(Double field3) {
        this.field3 = field3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [field1=" + this.field1 + 
                   ", field2=" + this.field2 + 
                   ", field3=" + this.field3 + "]";
    }

    public boolean isDefault(Function<Data, Object> getter) {
        Object defaultProperty = getter.apply(DEFAULTS);
        Object actualProperty = getter.apply(this);
        return defaultProperty != null // needed to support fields with no default value
            && defaultProperty.equals(actualProperty);
    }

    public boolean isNull(Function<Data, Object> getter) {
        return getter.apply(this) == null;
    }

    public boolean isSet(Function<Data, Object> getter) {
        return !this.isNull(getter) && !this.isDefault(getter);
    }
}
```

Here I've used a `private static` attribute to hold your `Data`'s default values and 3 methods to query any field state (default, null or set). In order to determine which field to query, these methods receive a `Function<Data, Object>`, which are given a `Data` instance and return an `Object` that is supposed to be the desired field. (If you stop to think it, getters can be seen as functions that take the instance as input and return a specific field of the instance).

So later, when you need to know how a certain field arrived in your JSON input, just use those 3 query methods to find out:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();

String json = "{\"field1\":null,\"field2\":20}";
Data data = m.readValue(json, Data.class);

System.out.println(data); // Data [field1=null, field2=20, field3=3.75]

System.out.println("field1 default ? " + data.isDefault(Data::getField1)); // false
System.out.println("field1 null ? " + data.isNull(Data::getField1)); // true
System.out.println("field1 set ? " + data.isSet(Data::getField1)); // false

System.out.println("field2 default ? " + data.isDefault(Data::getField2)); // false
System.out.println("field2 null ? " + data.isNull(Data::getField2)); // false
System.out.println("field2 set ? " + data.isSet(Data::getField2)); // true

System.out.println("field3 default ? " + data.isDefault(Data::getField3)); // true
System.out.println("field3 null ? " + data.isNull(Data::getField3)); // false
System.out.println("field3 set ? " + data.isSet(Data::getField3)); // false
```

Comment: This means that there is no way to discriminate between an absent value and a `null` value afterwards, which is desired.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense! This avoids using a map, as suggested in the other answers. Should one use the `==` operator to discriminate between absent and filled-in value?

Comment: @Dave Wait, do you need to know *later* when the default has been used? I thought you were asking about parsing the JSON only.

Comment: After parsing, I should be able to find out if the field was either filled in, set to null or was absent in the input JSON.

Comment: @Dave Updated my answer again, hope this time it will be of use.

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. One question, aren't we having a wrong behavior when the value of a field in the input JSON is exactly equal to the default value of that field? That's why I suggested using `==` instead of `equals`.

Comment: @Dave In that case, `isDefault()` would return `true`. I thought that if the incoming value is equal to the default value, then it doesn't matter whether the value was set or not. I chose to let `isDefault()` return `true` in this case.

Comment: @Dave Regarding `equals()` vs `==`, I suggest you always use `equals()` and check for `==` in the very first line.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the first option makes the most semantic sense. It also potentially allows for easier computation.

Where a field in java is null, it is implied that a value is missing, which matches the first option.

I suggest that you store these fields in a hash-map where the key is the JSON field name and the value is the JSON field's value. I also suggest you don't use an optional here (as it can add an unnecessary layer of complexity), and instead use either a null or non-null object in the hashmap.

```
HashMap<String, Value> jsonFields = new HashMap<String, Value>();
boolean hasField1 = false;
Value field1Value = null;
if(jsonFields.contains("field1"){ // It is present in the JSON file
    field1Value = jsonFields.get("field1"); // "null" here would mean that the JSON field was set to "null"
    hasField1 = true;
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what jackson-datatype-jdk8 is doing. It looks counter intuitive to me, hence the question.

Comment: @DaveTeezo What seems counter-intuitive?

Comment: The fact that `null` means `absent` and `Optional.empty` `null`.

Comment: BTW, my comment was made before your edit about the hash map. I was referring to your comment saying that the first option makes most sense.

Comment: @DaveTeezo Ah, well I guess it is a subjective matter. I'd say that **Optional.empty()** is also a way of directly saying "absent", but in a way that prevents NullPointerExceptions. http://huguesjohnson.com/programming/java/java8optional.html

Comment: @DaveTeezo Make sure you accept an answer so that others know that the question has been answered.

Comment: I will! I am still contemplating which answer is prefered.

Answer (score 1):

The second choice makes more sense to me. `null` means `null` and empty means not present.

However, `Optional` shouldn't really be used as a field.  [It's supposed to be used as an API return value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23464794/2616073).

Could you instead store the data in a `Map` that allows null values?  And if the key (your field) isn't present in the map, then return `Optional.empty` ?

Comment: This means that all fields are is reduced to one single `Map`?

Comment: possibly, doesn't have to be everything, just the ones that could be optional I guess

Answer (score 0):

Neither? I would annotate my POJO fields with @DefaultValue(). Then your possibilities are a null value or a non-null value specified in JSON, or the default if the field was omitted from JSON. And you can then just persist the POJO without any special per-field analysis.

Comment: The database holds the default value, which can be a complex query. Using `@DefaultValue` means that you are duplicating this into the application code, and also that you are sending the default values to the database.

Comment: So the DB supplies the default value if you don't include it in the query? Agreed then that annotating the default value isn't a good choice. You could annotate with a special default string value like "USE_DB_DEFAULT", as long as there's a string that wouldn't conflict with valid values. Check for that special string when persisting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with `Object` instead of `String`,  here's a solution I find elegant:

- use `Optional.empty();` if there is no value
- use `Optional.of(value)` if there is a value
- use `Optional.of(specialValue)` if the value is null

where `specialValue` is a static singleton you can easily test, for instance: `ObjectUtils.NULL` (from *commons.lang*).

Then you can easily test your optional:

```
if (optional.isPresent()) {
    if (ObjectUtils.NULL.equals(optional.get())) {
        // value is there and null
    } else {
        // value is there and not null
    }
} else {
    // value is not there 
}
```