# Transforming JSONArray string to Java POJO

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am trying to fiddle with ObjectMapper's properties to achieve the following, but did dot find a way till now

```
Context : We've following classes

class X {
     :
}

class C {
    private String c1;
    private String c2;
    private List<X> c3;
}

Input : A String that represents JSONArray. Ex : "[ {..}, {..} ]"
Output : Java Class 'C' with c1, c2 set as null and c3 set from input
```

I do not want to transform input to JSON string first and then create an instance of `C` myself and then set `c3` manually. Can I deserialize input JSON string as described above?

Comment: will this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320993/jackson-what-happens-if-a-property-is-missing) help ??

Comment: I just tried an example... it is possible to do like that...