# How to detect missing field when converting jsonObject to Model Object

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, oval

I am sending a `JsonObject` using web service. The method that receives the call has a method parameter of model Object for the corresponding  `JsonObject` Input being passed. The  `JsonObject` is successfully getting converted to model object but I am not able to test a few of my Responses from the model Object.

For example: if any mandatory field is missing in the input JSON or if any field in the input JSON is set to `null`, then in both these cases the model object field is coming out to be `null`.

I am not able to detect if the `null` is because of field missing or the field being set to `null`.

Can anybody suggest me a solution?

My last way out for this is, I will receive method parameter input as `String` and not my model Object and then using conditional checks, check the input string and get my Responses accordingly. But my JSON input object is very large and I am hoping there could be a better way out than this.

It is a Spring boot project.

Code Snippet:

```
JSON Object being sent

{"orgType":null, "orgLocation": "Geneva" , //other fields}


@RequestMapping(value="/addOrganizations", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addOrganization(@RequestBody Organization organization){
// code goes here
}
```

If I try with

```
{"orgType":null, "orgLocation": "Geneva" , //other fields}
```

or:

```
{"orgLocation": "Geneva" , //other fields}
```

and check with debugger inside `addOrganization()` method, then the value is `null` in both the cases.

Model class:

```
public class Organization{

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private String orgType;

private String orgLocation;

// other fields and getters and setters.

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was going through the links of StackOverflow and finally got an answer through this link

[Jackson: What happens if a property is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320993/jackson-what-happens-if-a-property-is-missing)

Thought might be helpful for somebody else.

Thanks